# Skip some ranges in postgresql sequence?

Tags: postgresql, sequence, psql

I want to skip some ranges in sequence:

```
Create sequence id_seq;
```

Consider I have a sequence as `Id_seq`.. And it starts from 100..

When it reaches to 199.. Then it should start with 1000 and when it reaches 1999 .. It should start with 10000..

```
setval(100,'Id_seq');
```

Whether `postgres` has any default configuration to do this?

Multiple process will use this sequence.. So assigning manually in process using `setval()` lead some difficulties..

Answer (score 2):

No there is nothing built in to do this. I've never heard of anyone wanting to do this before.

If you really care about the numbers you get then a sequence isn't the right thing for you anyway. You can get gaps in it quite easily. It's designed to generate differing numbers without impacting concurrency.